# How to use resource variable if resource was not created in Terraform

Tags: terraform

I want to enable or disable encryption RDS with Customer managed key by adding variable `create_kms_key` but always getting an error `Resource 'aws_kms_key.ami-kms-key' not found for variable 'aws_kms_key.ami-kms-key.arn'` when a resource "aws_kms_key" is not created.

create_kms_key = false

```
resource "aws_kms_key" "ami-kms-key" {
  count = "${var.create_kms_key ? 1 : 0}"
  description = "ami-kms-key"
  enable_key_rotation = true
}

resource "aws_db_instance" "default" {
  allocated_storage    = 20
  storage_type         = "gp2"
  engine               = "mysql"
  engine_version       = "5.7.19"
  instance_class       = "db.t2.micro"
  name                 = "encrypteddb"
  username             = "admin"
  password             = "admin"
  storage_encrypted    = true
  kms_key_id           = "${aws_kms_key.ami-kms-key.arn}"
}
```

I have tried `kms_key_id = "${var.create_kms_key ? aws_kms_key.ami-kms-key.arn : "" }"` and it didn't help

I don't want to create kms key every time I running terraform.
I expect to use default kms/not encrypted RDS or encrypted with Customer managed key according to `create_kms_key` variable.

How to skip `kms_key_id`in resource?

Thanks!

Comment: If you are using 0.12 you can modify your attempt to `kms_key_id = var.create_kms_key ? aws_kms_key.ami-kms-key.arn : null`

Comment: Matt, 
thank you for your comment, but I need to use 11 version

Comment: Then you would have to declare two resources: one with the kms and one without, and have a `count` in each with conditionals in each that are the reverse to the other.